# Error with Devise - Cannot run rails s or any devise commands

Tags: ruby, devise

I've recently added gem 'devise' but all of the sudden I can no longer run rails s or any devise commands without seeing this  Error message:

```
`c:3:in rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rai
s::Application::RoutesReloader:0x276cf60 @paths=["c:/Sites/code/omrails/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x2ab40c0>]> (Runt
meError)
        from c:65535:in `execute_if_updated'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from c:/Sites/code/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:47:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

#### Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'simple_form', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

ruby '1.9.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do 
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc2'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.1'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

#### Routes.rb

```
Omrails::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :installs
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

Comment: Can you add your `Gemfile` and `routes.rb` too ?

Comment: edited to add the files.  my apologies if the formatting is poor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can shifting to rails edge.

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem "devise", "~> 3.0.1"
```

(https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10559)